# How to split string of emails with different domains and no separator

Tags: python-3.x, string, split, data-cleaning

How can one separate a string of emails with no separator and different domains/number of letters after ‘@‘?

hello@you.comhi@me.com.secontact@you.com.brcontact@us.org

Is it possible to structure:
If ends with .br or .se: separate there
Else, separate after .com
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use regular expression ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/P1F3Gc/1)):

```py
import re

s = "hello@you.comhi@me.com.secontact@you.com.brcontact@us.org"

emails = re.findall(r"[^@]+@[^@]+(?:\.com|\.se|\.br|\.org)", s)
print(emails)
```

Prints:

```
['hello@you.com', 'hi@me.com.se', 'contact@you.com.br', 'contact@us.org']
```